# $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}=0 \implies a_i = k(b_i-\bar{b})$ for some constants $k, b_1, \cdots, b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove followings:

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}=0 \implies a_i = k(b_i-\bar{b})$ for some constants $k, b_1, \cdots, b_n$ where $\bar{b} = \frac{\sum{b_i}}{n}$

It seems very obvious, but I have no idea to prove it rigorously.

I think $k$ plays a critical role in this statement; it may not be hold if $k=1$.
Could you give some hint or details?

Comment: Well, this trivially holds if we take $k=1$ and $b_i=a_i$. 
Is there any other requirement for $b_i$?

Comment: Oh, it was very obvious statement... I think author use $k$ for convenience to progress main proof (It appears in proof of other theorem). thanks.

Comment: Actually, same holds if we take $b_i=\lambda a_i$  and $k=1/\lambda$. I wonder if converse statement holds?